# Where does 'url' in 'var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');' come from in Loopback 3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, loopbackjs, cloud-foundry

```js
app.start = function() {
  // start the web server
  return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');
    var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);
    if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
      var explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
      console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
    }
  });
};
```

I'm trying to route a Cloud Foundry app (that uses Loopback 3) to a context path `host.domain.com/this-path`.

At first, just using `cf create-route` and `cf map-route` didn't work. I'd get a 404 error, so I changed the root.js in my Loopback app to include `this-path.`

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = function(server) {
  // Install a `/` route that returns server status
  var router = server.loopback.Router();
  router.get('/this-path', server.loopback.status());
  server.use(router);
};
```

It was able to get the loopback status at `host.domain.com/this-path`, but API calls/additional paths won't work I just get errors like this. So then I tried changing the Loopback config.json's restApiRoot to include the path as well but that also gave me errors like this:

```
"error": {
        "statusCode": 404,
        "name": "Error",
        "message": "Cannot POST /this-path/api/make-something",
        "status": 404,
        "stack": "Cannot POST /this-path/api/make-something\n    at raiseUrlNotFoundError (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/loopback/server/middleware/url-not-found.js:21:17)\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)\n    at trim_prefix (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)\n    at /home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7\n    at Function.process_params (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)\n    at next (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)\n    at /home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15\n    at next (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:260:14)\n    at Function.handle (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)\n    at router (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)\n    at trim_prefix (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)\n    at /home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7\n    at Function.process_params (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)\n    at next (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)\n    at nosniff (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/dont-sniff-mimetype/index.js:4:5)"
    }
}
```

So now I'm wondering Where does `url` in `var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');` come from and can I change it so my app listens on `host.domain.com/this-path?`

Comment: In these cases what I tend to do is have a look in the actual source code of the library. I did not check the specifics myself but I found the logic to compose the 'url' at https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/3.x-latest/lib/application.js#L605